# Issue with QR code Layout item plug-in

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I need through a QR code give an https address, with parameters, like `https://MyWebSite/Mywebpage?Myparam=1234`. The objective is to open a specific page of MyWebsite, and pass the parameter `MyParam` for further use in the page (i.e. prefill specific fields depending on the value passed).

I do not find the correct way of setting up this string, knowing that:
`https://MyWebSite/Mywebpage` is a constant, as well as `?Myparam=` and `1234` is the content of an attribute field in the shapefile.
The problems start with the char `?` That does not seem to be accepted/recognised.

I tested with the `concat` function, or with double pipes, but without success, the `concat` does not seem to be executed and is literally part of the QR code generated.

Any idea to have it work?

I also posted this question on github/qrbarcodeitem-plugin.

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: Where do you try to make the string?

Comment: Windows, QGIS 3.28.4. I edit in the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression worked:

```sql
[%'https://MyWebSite/Mywebpage?Myparam=' ||
attribute(
  @atlas_feature,
  'value'  -- field name containing 1234 etc.
)%]
```

Expression window:
[image]

[image]

QR Code online decoder:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. With the attribute fonction, I did not succeed but directly with the name (pa_uid) of the attribute, it worked. 
[%'https://cverstichel8.wixsite.com/website/protoform?pannum=' ||  @z_PrefixPanneau  || "pa_uid" %]